# How to show range selection input dialog in excel using officejs

Tags: excel, office-js

I want to show range selection dialog box, something as shown in below image from my office addin, When user click on range input box in my office addin, i want it shows following dialog, what are the options available today using officejs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they only way you currently can do this today is by using the Bindings API which will allow you to show a ref-edit prompt in Excel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.bindings?view=excel-js-1.9#addfrompromptasync-bindingtype--callback-

Comment: hello @keyur patel, in excel online, it shows prompt but it only allows to edit the text by keyboard or only shows selected range, its a model dialog with no option of selecting in the backend, i was expecting same like what i showed in the picture

Comment: also can you please tell me how to get selected range, i didn't find anyway,

Comment: Answers without code on a coding support site :(

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to accomplish this, but here is everything you need:

```js
const promptForRangeBindingId = (): Promise<string> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const handleResult = (result: Office.AsyncResult<Office.Binding>) => {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                resolve(result.value.id);
            } else {
                reject(result.error.message);
            }
        };
        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync(
            Office.BindingType.Matrix,
            handleResult
        );
    });

const getAddressesByBindingId = (bindingId: string): Promise<string> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Excel.run((ctx) => {
            const binding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem(bindingId);
            const range = binding.getRange();
            range.load('address');
            return ctx.sync().then(() => resolve(range.address));
        })
            .catch((error) => reject(error))
            .finally(() => {
                return Office.context.document.bindings.releaseByIdAsync(
                    bindingId
                );
            });
    });

const promptForAddressRange = async (): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const bindingId = await promptForRangeBindingId();
        const address = await getAddressesByBindingId(bindingId);
        return address;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
};
export {
    promptForAddressRange,
    promptForRangeBindingId,
    getAddressesByBindingId,
};
```

Then to consume the addresses, just call the `promptForAddressRange` function.

```js
async function getAddresses() {
   // make sure to wrap in try/catch
   return await promptForAddressRange();
}
```